# How to use RF24Mesh on Raspbian in Qt

Tags: raspbian, qt

I want to use the RF24Mesh library in my QT application in Raspbian Jessie.

I can compile the example and run it (with the make command) but when I include libs to my QT app, it gives the error:

```
Undefined reference to RF24:RF24(unsigned short , unsigned short , unsigned INT)
```

I think it is because it cannot find the CPP files.

Comment: What does your compile command look like? Do you reference the new included libraries in that compile command?